# How to change incorrect Django Path (django.__path__)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have pip installed django into my project and now it seems that my Django Project is confused about what Django installation should it be running.

When I run

```
python manage.py shell
```

and

```
import django
django.__path__
```

Shell returns incorrect path:

```
['D:\\project_2\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\django']
```

Since I am working on project_1, I expect the following path:

```
['D:\\project_1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\django']
```

Is there a quick fix?

Comment: activate the right virtualenv first..?

Comment: I've tried running activate myvenvname but django.__path__ still seems to be incorrect

Comment: ..it looks like your virtualenv is named "venv" for both projects, so you'd probably need to be very careful about which directory you're in when running activate...

Comment: Activate the venv and run this ** python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())" **. It can help for debugging the django version

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right virtual environment ?
If using conda a better practice is to do environment by project, 
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html,
Because the `Django path` refers to the location where your environment is setup

Comment: Ok, I have now masked my project_2 venv folder and I get this error:
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

I am running a wrong virtual environment. Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: But it is installed. When I manually check my venv folder, django is there. I will try reinstalling I guess.

Comment: hey, can you write out the result of `conda activate <your_env>`, `conda list` and ´PYTHONPATH´?

Comment: I think I've fixed it. I've messed up my Windows Environment Variables and they were causing trouble. Thanks everyone for help.